# Include external javaScript CSS in laravel 5

Tags: javascript, laravel

I m naive  to laravel and have to include external javaScript file which is in public/js folder and there is no folder like assets.

Comment: <script src="{{ asset('js/library.min.js') }}"></script> ..folder public/js/library.min.js

Comment: I dont have asset folder then how I can use asset  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add your external `js` and `css` under public folder, then

for css,
lets say you want to load a css file called `demo.css` located inside `public` folder, then

```
 <link href="{{asset('demo.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
```

for js

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="{{asset('demo.js')}}"></script>
```

Comment: did you add your `css` and `js` files inside public folder?

Comment: yeah I added  <script type="text/javascript" src="{{asset('../../../public/js/treejquery.js')}}"></script>

Comment: should I define it  in routes.php